# Cp does not copy file

Tags: cp

This does not copy the file.
I am owner of both directories.

And there are no messages?

```
cd /home/andy/.mozilla/seamonkey/4e39n1np.default/
cp -f bookmarks.html /home/andy/.mozilla/firefox/mltw8z53.default-1516629000620/
```

File exists. File can't be moved in file explorer. I even deleted the "Firefox bookmarks file" and copied Seamonkey bookmarks file there??

Adding the output of namei -

f:  /home/andy/.mozilla/seamonkey/4e39n1np.default/bookmarks.html

```
Drwxr-xr-x root root / 
drwxr-xr-x root root home 
drwxrwxr-x andy andy andy 
drwxrw-rw- andy andy .mozilla 
drwxrw-rw- andy andy seamonkey 
drwxrwxrwx andy andy 4e39n1np.default 
-rw-r--r-- andy andy bookmarks.html
```

f: /home/andy/.mozilla/firefox/mltw8z53.default-            1516629000620/bookmarks.html

```
Drwxr-xr-x root root / 
drwxr-xr-x root root home 
drwxrwxr-x andy andy andy 
drwxrw-rw- andy andy .mozilla 
drwxrwxrwx andy andy firefox 
drwx------ andy andy mltw8z53.default-1516629000620 
-rw-r--r-- andy andy bookmarks.html
```

@wave5459

andyk_~/Downloads$ rm /home/andy/.mozilla/firefox/mltw8z53.default-1516629000620/bookmarks.html
andyk_~/Downloads$

File is deleted. But Firefox recreates it. :-(

Comment: It should have copied, logically. What happens when you try it using File Explorer?

And I know you're the owner, but what happens if you try "sudo"? 
Does bookmarks.html even exist? Are messages maybe piped to /dev/null?

Comment: file exists. Neither sudo nor file explorer work.

Comment: Add the output of `namei -lx /home/andy/.mozilla/seamonkey/4e39n1np.default/bookmarks.html /home/andy/.mozilla/firefox/mltw8z53.default-1516629000620/bookmarks.html`, please

Comment: f: /home/andy/.mozilla/seamonkey/4e39n1np.default/bookmarks.html
Drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root home
drwxrwxr-x andy andy andy
drwxrw-rw- andy andy .mozilla
drwxrw-rw- andy andy seamonkey
drwxrwxrwx andy andy 4e39n1np.default
-rw-r--r-- andy andy bookmarks.html
f: /home/andy/.mozilla/firefox/mltw8z53.default-1516629000620/bookmarks.html
Drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root home
drwxrwxr-x andy andy andy
drwxrw-rw- andy andy .mozilla
drwxrwxrwx andy andy firefox
drwx------ andy andy mltw8z53.default-1516629000620
-rw-r--r-- andy andy bookmarks.html

Comment: please add the output to your question (not a comment).  It can be formatted in the question and is easier to read.

Comment: I've updated the output in the description for him. And given that you want to forcibly overwrite the bookmarks in firefox, I'd like to see the output of `rm 
/home/andy/.mozilla/firefox/mltw8z53.default-1516629000620/bookmarks.html`

Comment: If Firefox recreates it, then try closing Firefox and Seamonkey before messing with files in their profile directories.

Comment: @muru While that advice is fine for copying files, I'm not sure if that's the right way to go since Seamonkey and Firefox might have different bookmark structures.

Comment: @wave5459 hence my phrasing "messing with"

Comment: @muru Ha. Noted.

Comment: The title of this question should probably be changed from "cp doesn't copy file" to something like "How to import Seamonkey bookmarks to Firefox?" - I don't see any evidence that the file copy operation itself actually failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the simplest resolution you seek isn't so much Ubuntu related as it is Firefox related . You want to import your bookmarks from Seaborn to Firefox I presume. 
Here's a suggested response on a link I found that seems to have worked in that case -

> If you have a SeaMonkey version that uses places.sqlite then you can
>   copy this file from the SeaMonkey profile folder to the Firefox
>   profile folder.
>
> http://kb.mozillazine.org/Transferring_data_to_a_new_profile_-_Firefox
>   http://kb.mozillazine.org/Transferring_data_to_a_new_profile_-_SeaMonkey

Source - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/963390

Let me know if it works.

Comment: You get the gold star. Copying places.sqlite to Firefox profile folder worked.

Comment: @fixit7 Glad it helped!  Please accept the answer if you think it served the purpose sufficiently :D